# QTCreator No Rule

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Today I opened my QTCreator project and now it is telling me that:

:-1: error: No rule to make target `Diskbutler'.  Stop.

I have nothing changed. Maybe Xcode was updated. Any Idea why this error occur? I have no idea with this information QTCreator gives to me. I saw something about pro file and missing files, but everything looks ok:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-06-24T21:31:38
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += widgets
QT       += xml
QT       += network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

VERSION = 2.3.0.3

macx: ICON = diskbutler.icns
TARGET = Diskbutler
TEMPLATE = app


# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
DEFINES += BS_GUI
DEFINES += APP_VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
DEFINES += MAC
#DEFINES += UNICODE _UNICODE



# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

HEADERS_CONTROLS = \
  controls/QtWaitingSpinner.h
SOURCES_CONTROLS = \
  controls/QtWaitingSpinner.cpp
HEADERS_FOXSDK = \
  foxsdk/bass.h \
  foxsdk/tchar.h \
  foxsdk/FoxSDKBurningLib.h \
  foxsdk/FoxSDKExport.h \
  foxsdk/FoxSDKDefinitions.h \
  foxsdk/FoxSDKUnicode.h
HEADERS_NODES = \
  nodes/QDataItem.h \
  nodes/qdiskitem.h \
  nodes/qaudiotrackitem.h \
  nodes/qmediumitem.h \
  nodes/qsessionitem.h \
  nodes/qtrackitem.h \
  nodes/qfilesysitem.h \
  nodes/qfilesys_iso9660item.h \
  nodes/qfilesys_udfitem.h \
  nodes/qfolderitem.h \
  nodes/qfileitem.h
SOURCES_NODES = \
  nodes/QDataItem.cpp \
  nodes/qdiskitem.cpp \
  nodes/qaudiotrackitem.cpp \
  nodes/qmediumitem.cpp \
  nodes/qsessionitem.cpp \
  nodes/qtrackitem.cpp \
  nodes/qfilesysitem.cpp \
  nodes/qfilesys_iso9660item.cpp \
  nodes/qfilesys_udfitem.cpp \
  nodes/qfolderitem.cpp \
  nodes/qfileitem.cpp
HEADERS_UTILS = \
  utils/utils_common.h \
  utils/vrulemanager.h
SOURCES_UTIS = \
  utils/utils_common.cpp \
  utils/vrulemanager.cpp
HEADERS_RIBBON = \
  ribbon/ribbon.h \
  ribbon/ribbonbuttongroup.h \
  ribbon/ribbontabcontent.h
SOURCES_RIBBON = \
  ribbon/ribbon.cpp \
  ribbon/ribbonbuttongroup.cpp \
  ribbon/ribbontabcontent.cpp
HEADERS_ZMODULES = \
  zmodules/zfileiconprovider.h \
  zmodules/zimageloader.h \
  zmodules/zplaylistloader.h \
  zmodules/zreplacefiledialog.h
SOURCES_ZMODULES = \
  zmodules/zfileiconprovider.cpp \
  zmodules/zimageloader.cpp \
  zmodules/zplaylistloader.cpp \
  zmodules/zreplacefiledialog.cpp
HEADERS_DIALOGS = \
   dialogs/burndialog.h \
   dialogs/vcddialog.h \
   dialogs/vdiskpropertydialog.h \
   dialogs/vpropertydialog.h \
   dialogs/zpropertydialogfoxfile.h
SOURCES_DIALOGS = \
   dialogs/burndialog.cpp \
   dialogs/vcddialog.cpp \
   dialogs/vdiskpropertydialog.cpp \
   dialogs/vpropertydialog.cpp \
   dialogs/zpropertydialogfoxfile.cpp
HEADERS_PROJECT = \
    project/zproject_bluray.h \
    project/zproject_explore.h \
    project/zproject_videodvd.h
SOURCES_PROJECT = \
    project/zproject_bluray.cpp \
    project/zproject_explore.cpp \
    project/zproject_videodvd.cpp
HEADERS_STRATEGY = \
    strategy/zimport_strategy.h \
    strategy/zimport_strategy_fixedfolder.h \
    strategy/zimport_strategy_nosubfolder.h \
    strategy/zimport_strategy_suffixallowed.h
SOURCES_STRATEGY = \
    strategy/zimport_strategy_fixedfolder.cpp \
    strategy/zimport_strategy_nosubfolder.cpp \
    strategy/zimport_strategy_suffixallowed.cpp
HEADERS_MODEL = \
    model/zInfoTableModel.h \
    model/zallocation_table_model.h
SOURCES_MODEL = \
    model/zInfoTableModel.cpp \
    model/zallocation_table_model.cpp
HEADERS_HEX = \
    hex/QHexView.h \
    hex/QScanBoard.h
SOURCES_HEX = \
    hex/QHexView.cpp \
    hex/QScanBoard.cpp

SOURCES += $${SOURCES_CONTROLS} \
        $${SOURCES_NODES} \
        $${SOURCES_UTIS} \
        $${SOURCES_RIBBON} \
        $${SOURCES_ZMODULES} \
        $${SOURCES_DIALOGS} \
        $${SOURCES_PROJECT} \
        $${SOURCES_STRATEGY} \
        $${SOURCES_MODEL} \
        $${SOURCES_HEX} \
        CommonTreeWidget.cpp \
        audiotaginfo.cpp \
        configdialog.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
        mdichild_base.cpp \
        mdichild_deviceinfo.cpp \
        mdichild_dialog.cpp \
        mdichild_diskinfo.cpp \
        mdichild_hex.cpp \
        mdichild_scan.cpp \
        settingspages.cpp \
        utils/messanger.cpp \
        xbelgenerator.cpp \
        xbelhandler.cpp


HEADERS += $${HEADERS_CONTROLS} \
        $${HEADERS_FOXSDK} \
        $${HEADERS_NODES} \
        $${HEADERS_UTILS} \
        $${HEADERS_RIBBON} \
        $${HEADERS_ZMODULES} \
        $${HEADERS_DIALOGS} \
        $${HEADERS_PROJECT} \
        $${HEADERS_STRATEGY} \
        $${HEADERS_MODEL} \
        $${HEADERS_HEX} \
        CommonTreeWidget.h \
        audiotaginfo.h \
        configdialog.h \
        mainwindow.h \
        mdichild_base.h \
        mdichild_deviceinfo.h \
        mdichild_dialog.h \
        mdichild_diskinfo.h \
        mdichild_hex.h \
        mdichild_scan.h \
        settingspages.h \
        utils/messanger.h \
        xbelgenerator.h \
        xbelhandler.h

TRANSLATIONS = diskbutler_de.ts
CODECFORSRC = UTF-8

OTHER_FILES += \
  diskbutler_de.ts

FORMS += \
        dialogs/burndialog.ui \
        dialogs/vcddialog.ui \
        dialogs/vdiskpropertydialog.ui \
        dialogs/vpropertydialog.ui \
        dialogs/zpropertydialogfoxfile.ui \
        mainwindow.ui \
        ribbon/ribbonbuttongroup.ui \
        ribbon/ribbontabcontent.ui \
        zmodules/zreplacefiledialog.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    diskbutler.qrc

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD $$PWD/project $$PWD/nodes $$PWD/strategy $$PWD/FoxSDK $$PWD/utils $$PWD/dialogs $$PWD/model
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD $$PWD/zmodules $$PWD/ribbon $$PWD/controls $$PWD/hex
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/FoxSDK

macx:{
LIBS += -L$$PWD/FoxSDK/ -lFoxSDK
LIBS += -L$$PWD/FoxSDK/ -lbass
MediaFiles.files += FoxSDK/libFoxSDK.dylib
MediaFiles.files += FoxSDK/libFoxSDKFXToolkit.dylib
MediaFiles.files += FoxSDK/libbass.dylib
MediaFiles.files += diskbutler_de.qm
MediaFiles.path = Contents/MacOS
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += MediaFiles
}

DISTFILES += \
    diskbutler_de.ts
```

Comment: Did you try to re-run qmake ? It will regenerate the Makefile.

Comment: Yes, but the error still exists, make throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe it is an Xcode issue. I have uninstalled and re-installed QT and now it is again working. Maybe the Xcode update cause this problem.